# Can't see my server on an azure vm

Tags: azure, angular, angular-cli

I have an Azure vm with Ubuntu 12 and I want to make an Angular2 server with angular-cli. When I run `ng serve --port 80` I just can't see the page with a browser. When I check with CURL from the vm I can see the HTML properly but I get an error when I try to see it from the internet.

The strangest thing is that anything else I try works perfectly, I also have an old node server on the vm and when I run that I can see it normally from CURL and from the internet.

Comment: "I get an error..." Mind sharing it?

Comment: i guess it's a http connection error. firewall? try to use port higher than 1000

Comment: Is your "old node" listening on the same port (80/TCP) when it works? Make sure your `ng serve` thing binds to `0.0.0.0:80` instead of `127.0.0.1:80`.

Comment: @evilSnobu I tried a whole lot of ports, long story short it doesn't matter 80, 8080, 3000 ... still works the same. How do I make sure to bind on `0.0.0.0:80`instead of `127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: @DanWilson I don't exactly get an error, just the browser telling me that it cannot access the website as if it wasn't running.

Comment: `sudo netstat -pan` should answer the binding question.

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2375. Apparently you have to do `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @evilSnobu And that worked ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so apparently I needed to specify host : `sudo ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80`.

github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2375

Thanks to [evilSnobu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4148708/evilsnobu).